# cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute setHeader is not allowed to appear in element headerName (Camel)

Tags: xml, spring-boot, xsd, apache-camel

I have seen a bunch of explaination, even on this site, about the error above... but no one was sufficiently clear about this two points:

1. Why appears this error?
2. How can I correct it exactly? What must I change in Camel/Spring boot project to make things work (what files, what configurations, what import of xsd? I must change POM? Where? Etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache Camel metamodel has been modified. You need to adapt the model or to point to the version of the xsd matching the version of your model.

if you are migrating from a 2.x to 3.x version, see https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_setheader_and_setproperty_in_xml_dsl

So migrate

```
<setHeader headerName="foo"><simple>Hello ${body}</simple></setHeader>
```

To

```
<setHeader name="foo"><simple>Hello ${body}</simple></setHeader>
```

To adapt to the correct version of xsd, you need to change the xsi:schemaLocation and point to a specific version instead of the "generic one". So replace something like https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd by https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.25.4.xsd or https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.17.0.xsd

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are validating a document against a schema, and the document is not valid against the schema; specifically, it has an attribute called `setHeader` on an element called `headerName`, and the schema does not allow that attribute.

To correct it, remove the attribute.

It looks from your question as if you aren't sure what XML document is being validated, and where to find it. I'm afraid I can't help you with that.

Comment: I cannot remove the attribute.

Comment: Then you must either (a) change the schema to allow it, or (b) not validate against that schema.